# Angular 2 Binding to Array Value

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind to the value of an array in my template view. In AngularJS I accomplished this as follows

```
 <div dx-text-box="{bindingOptions: {
       value: 'mainTableData[0].{{childControl.FieldName}}'
 }}"></div>
```

This worked fine but fails in Angular2, below is what I tried.

```
<dx-text-box
       [(value)]="mainTableData[0].{{childControl.FieldName}}">
</dx-text-box>
```

What would be the correct way to do this now? I have tried changing to to a function which returns the correct array value but this also fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<dx-text-box
       [(value)]="mainTableData[0].childControl.FieldName">
</dx-text-box>
```

Comment: Apologies, I have tried this also though, It seems to look for a value of 'childControl.Fieldname' rather than the value that FieldName equates to. Fails with the same error I pasted below.

Comment: That does nothing. [value] binds the components value to the input. (value) binds the input to the component [(value)] is two way data-binding and since his div has no input data in it [(value)] serve no purpose.

Comment: Could u define a new `mainTableData` array in your component and try the following:
`[(ngModel)]="mainTableData[0].childControl.FieldName"`
Fill your array with a fake data.

Comment: Or just define a new array the tell us what is the result

Comment: Also you can try to put  `?` after `mainTableData[0]` .

Comment: If i define a new array I get the same result. If I put mainTableData[0].AgentSurname this works correctly as AgentData is the value that childControl.FieldName should resolve to. I have also tried putting the ? and this fails saying mainTableData[0]?childControl.FieldName requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be something like this (assuming : `mainTableData[0].childControl.FieldName` is on your component.ts)

```
<dx-text-box
       [value]="mainTableData[0].childControl.FieldName">
</dx-text-box>
```

If you can also add custom attributes by doing :

```
<div [attr.dx-text-box] = "{bindingOptions: {
   value: 'mainTableData[0].{{childControl.FieldName}}'}}">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this also, this fails with the following error.  self.parentView.parentView.parentView.parentView.context.mainTableData is undefined

Comment: Where do you call your `dx-text-box` ? Can you post the component.ts file ?

Comment: This is called in the template, there isnt any code related to this in the component.ts. Its an empty class that loads the template and the mainTableData is on the service.

Comment: So `value` is a custom attribute ?

Comment: @user3218507 Also that sound weird. Why would you need a `value` attribute in empty component ?

Comment: Sorry, its a devextreme control, I am importing it from their components.

Comment: @user3218507 so you don't even have a `dx-text-box` component right ?

Comment: I am importing a DxTextBoxModule from devextreme. I have got this working by using mainTableData[0].AgentTitle as a test. AgentTitle is what the contro.fieldname variable should resolve to if I can get the binding to work.

Comment: @user3218507 I edited my answer. I'm not familiar with devextreme nor angular 1 so I can't help you that much on that part

Answer (score 0):

Could you potentially use a function to get your value rather than do it in the template?

```
<dx-text-box
       [value]="getMyValue(childControl.FieldName)" (valueChanged)="updateValue($event)>
</dx-text-box>
```

Inside your parent component:-

```
public getMyValue(name) {
    return this.mainTableData[0][name];
}

public updateValue(event) {
    console.log("new value", event.target.value);
}
```

Inside your `dx-text-box` component:-

```
@Ouput public valueChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

public functionThatsFiredWhenChangesHappen(value) {
    this.valueChanged.emit(value);
}
```

Comment: Unforunatly not, value can only take a string.

Comment: Well that function will return a string - I guess (without seeing your `mainTableData` array)

Comment: When I set it to a function such as [(value)]="test()" I get the following error      Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 13 in [test()=$event]

Comment: Thats was my fault, it works when I set it to 1 way binding. Just need to figure out how to get it to update, the dx-text-box component is a devextreme component, not my own

Comment: Did you follow this https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/blob/master/examples/app/app.component.html ?

Comment: Nope havent seen that before. Does that give a way to update the value when I change the array?

Comment: Well yes, it's using reactive forms so the form values can be accessed. https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive this is pretty good for learning reactive forms. The examples component is pretty comprehensive though.

Comment: Do you know why I cant use a function in 2 way binding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138953/discussion-between-joe-keene-and-user3218507).